# How to install npm behind proxy?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I read all the stuff about this problem but none of them worked.

I got `npm ERR! code E418`

or

```
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/expo failed, reason
drinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

if you know the proxy informations:

```
$ npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
$ npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```